# Can I patch an object method using a decorator

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest

Challenge: Patching/mocking a method call in a remote class to return a known piece of data.

I have a whole series of tests that look like:

```
@pytest.mark.gen_test
def test_assignment5(app):
    with patch.object(BaseHandler, 'get_current_user') as mock_user:
        mock_user.return_value = {"name": '1_kiz'}
        with patch.object(BaseHandler, 'get_auth_state') as mock_state:
            mock_state.return_value = { "course_id": "course_2",
                                        "course_role": "Instructor",
                                        "course_title": "A title",
                                    }
            r = yield async_requests.get(app.url + "/assignment?course_id=course_2&assignment_id=assign_a")
    assert r.status_code == 200
    response_data = r.json()   
    assert response_data["success"] == False
    assert response_data["note"] == "Assignment assign_a does not exist"
```

(`app` is the core method for my application, and `get_current_user` & `get_auth_state` use information outside the scope of the app to get a value, so need *fudged*)

..... the repeating `with` segments offend my sensibility of good-looking code.

I know I could pull the return-value dictionaries to top-level variables, and that would reduce *some* of the repeated code, however I'm still repeating the `with patch.object` stuff every time.

Reading https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch I know I could simply decorate each test, however

```
user_kiz = { ... }
auth_inst = { ... }

....

@pytest.mark.gen_test
@patch('BaseHandler.get_current_user', return_value = user_kiz)
@patch('BaseHandler.get_auth_state', return_value = auth_inst)
def test_assignment5a(app, kiz):
    r = yield async_requests.get(app.url + "/assignment?course_id=course_2&assignment_id=assign_a")
    assert r.status_code == 200
    response_data = r.json()   
    assert response_data["success"] == False
    assert response_data["note"] == "Assignment assign_a does not exist"
```

just gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BaseHandler'` error.

**Is** there a way to patch/mock a method call in a remote class, allowing me to set the `current_user` & `auth_state` dictionaries for each call?

(ultimately, I will also need to test for different users, and different auth_states)

Answer (score 0):

To replace a call like this:

```
with patch.object(a, 'b', c):
```

with a decorator, you'd use:

```
@patch.object(a, 'b', c)
```

You had switched to the string form

```
@patch(..., ...)
```

The string form requires the full import path as the first argument